# Use Service Account to Access GCP API to Set IAM Policy for Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I saw some half-related posts but none of them was helpful enough.

I have a GCP Service-Account `sa1` under a project named `testProject`.
I've created a key-pair for the Service-Account.
I want to use the service account in order to set IAM Policy for the project `testProject`.

I gave the Service-Account both `Owner` and `Security Admin` roles which contain the required policy: `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy`.

However, when I'm trying to use nodejs sdk in order to authenticate with my Service-Account and call `setIamPolicy` I get a `403` error with message:

```
'Permission 'resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/test-project-111111' (or it may not exist).'
```

If I try to call `getIamPolicy` then it is working just fine, the problem is only with the `set`.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        credentials: {
            private_key: <service-account-sa1-private-key>,
            client_email: <service-account-sa1-email-address>,
        },
        scopes: this.scopes,
    });

    const resourceClient = google.cloudresourcemanager({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: auth,
    });

    const setIamPolicyResponse = await resourceClient.projects.setIamPolicy({
        resource: 'projects/test-project-111111',
        requestBody: {
            policy: <policy>
        },
    });
```

The sample was modified a bit, but I'm sure that the policy I'm setting is valid (first I use `getIamPolicy` and then just make a tiny modification and then trying the `set` and anyway the error I'm getting back is 403 (not 400))

I'm also sure that the project name is correct (because the `getIamPolicy` request is working fine for the same project name).

Is it possible to do what I want?
What is the root cause of this error?

Comment: Where are you running your nodejs code from? Local machine/laptop? Compute engine?

Comment: @GlenYu from my personal mac. does it matter?

Comment: 1) Include the code that shows reading the IAM policy. 2) Show the value for `scopes: this.scopes`. 3) My guess is that the scope requested does not allow permission.

Comment: As John already alluded to above, there are scopes, and for Compute Engine in particular, the [default scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) is unable to do anything with IAM.  But then it wouldn't be able to run `getIamPolicy` as well, but that's why I wanted to verify where you were running it from.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was my fault for misunderstanding that Service Account on GCP is both principal and resource.
I added the roles over the Service Account itself, and not the project that it belongs to (I added it through the Service Account page in GCP console instead of doing through the IAM page of the project).
Not sure why the `getIamPolicy` worked though, maybe there were more wrong configuration I applied that created this mix.
Anyway, once roles were added in the project level, everything worked.
Thanks.